# How to handle this error IOFiles MODULE: Encryped data don't stored, an IO error ocurred:java.io.FileNotFoundException (access is denied?

Tags: java

Iam working in `Attribute Based Encryption` in netbeans , when try to save file in folder after encryption the following error appear `IOFiles MODULE: Encryped DET-ABE data don't stored, an IO error ocurred: java.io.FileNotFoundException` `(access is denied)`.The folder exists in the C drive and I am using windows 7 64bit. Even after changing the drive and folder also I am getting the same exception. I made all permissions in this folder full control read and write in it.What is the problem in this case.What i should do to solve that.

```
IOFiles MODULE: Encryped DET-ABE data don't stored, an IO error ocurred:    java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\latest\SearchEncryptedMaster\src\papers (Access is denied)
IOFiles MODULE: DET-ABE DECRYPTION MODULE: Reading encryped DET-ABE data don't found in file D:\latest\SearchEncryptedMaster\src\papers\.   java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\latest\SearchEncryptedMaster\src\papers (Access is denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception shows you provided a folder path to `FileOutputStream`. FileOutputStream only accept file path.

> Ex : D:\latest\SearchEncryptedMaster\src\papers\fileName.txt

Please refer following Java doc link for understand FileOutputStream

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html